# How do I get Inline links in a paragraph grouped with images and that are interactive?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I currently have about 4-6 sentences that each come from different articles. They are displayed after each other in a TedxtBox that wraps the text. What I want to do is make the sentences interactive (hover/click) and also add a small icon at the end of the sentences with the same interaction. Each sentence should have individual events attached to it.

How would you recommend me doing this? I have seriously have no clue at all.
Thanks

Comment: did you want that text to be editable as well? Any other compelling reason to keep that text in a TextBox?

Comment: No it can be done with another control, but the text needs to be in a wrapping textbox-like format.

Comment: Maybe have a look at this article "Creating Actionlinks in a Silverlight RichTextBox":
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/InteractiveText.aspx

Comment: Use Listbox control having a textbox inside its Data template inside it.

Comment: @Malcolm: That wouldn't give me wrapped text though. It more like inline links. just like florian gave me to link for below.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with text not wrapping in the listbox is that the listbox, by design, does not restrict the size of its child objects; they can expand past the visible border of the box, at which time a scrollbar is displayed to enable the user to scroll across/down the list.

If, at the point that you create and populate the listbox, you set the Width of the child items (whether TextBox or TextBlock) to a known value (for instance, the width of the listbox minus any margin) and then set TextWrapping.Wrap as normal, your text will wrap as you expect.

Comment: Yes but the they will not be inline with each other. Just imagine a paragraph of text with 7 sentences and no line-breaks. Then make each sentence a link or put link in the middle of the text. Thanks anyway :)